# Unable to get data from firestore when deployed spring boot app on app engine

Tags: spring-boot, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have deployed spring boot service on app engine, it shows that connection to firebase is successful but unable to fetch any result. Everything is working fine when I am running it locally. This is how app is making connection to fireStore. I am setting the serviceAccounnts.json in GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable

```
FirestoreOptions firestoreOptions =
                    FirestoreOptions.getDefaultInstance().toBuilder()
                        .setProjectId(PROJECT_ID)
                        .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault())
                        .build();
```

In Service bean, the fireStore Instance is initialized as

```
public static Firestore dbFireStore = FirestoreOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();
```

I am fetching data like this

```
CollectionReference collectionReference = dbFireStore.collection("Collection_Name")
.document("Document_Name")
.collection("SubCollection_Name");

ApiFuture<QuerySnapshot> querySnapshot = collectionReference.whereEqualTo("Search_Field", "Search_Value").get();

List<QueryDocumentSnapshot> queryDocumentSnapshot = querySnapshot.get().getDocuments();
```

The list returned here is empty but expected size was 1 and working fine on local.

Comment: Did you double check if the project_ID were the same? Can you log this command and compare the results? `((ServiceAccountCredentials)GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault()).getProjectId()`

Comment: Thanks @guillaumeblaquiere this worked, actually I was trying to make connection to other database and I thought connection was made, now I am using the same project, everything is working fine now

Answer (score 0):

From your code, it looks like you're initializing Firestore with default credentials. To understand, App Engine [automatically retrieves the service account credentials](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#automatically) to call Google Cloud APIs.

However if the environment variable **GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS** is set, ADC (Application Default Credentials) uses that service account file that the variable points to and permission problems will arise if App Engine can't find that service account credential. You should check your App Engine loggings on Google Cloud Console.

What I suggest for your App Engine build is that you remove that environment variable and try again.